# How to solve proper url linking in php

Tags: php

I am facing difficulties in providing proper url links.I have directory tree as:

application[  [layout:  {header.php}] [view:{login.php, contact.php}] {index.php}]

index.php:

```
<?php include 'layouts/header.php';?>
```

header.php:

```
<>
<><"index.php">Home</></>
<><"view/login.php">Login</></>
<><"view/contact.php">Contact</></>
</>
```

login.php:

```
 <?php include '../layouts/header.php';?>
```

Problem is When i opened index.php at the beginning it takes right url. From here it takes proper login.php.But I am in login.php and clicking Home(i.e. index.php) it takes different url something like application/view/index.php.

How to give proper url link? so that all link will ie in sub or outside of it?

### Don't know why people down voted If you didnt understood ask where you didnt,rather down voted.It will give -ve response to the asker and to ask anything to anyone

Comment: You can get all values in *php* as well as *jquery* by providing `name` to each of controls.

Comment: let us suppose then..?

Comment: yes use serialize for getting values, or you can use name attribute if you want to use php

Comment: remove view/ from url

Comment: simple mvc no proper framework.
if i remove view then it goes /application/index.php but it should go to /application/view/index.php.

Answer (score 0):

This is depending on your requirements OR also you can get all the value using PHP or jQuery.